# How to install Apache2::AuthCookie in Centos 6?

Tags: apache, perl, centos6

I am trying to install Apache2::AuthCookie on a CentOS 6 machine with the following command:

```
cpanm Apache2::AuthCookie
```

but I get the following error:

> --> Working on Apache2::AuthCookie
>   Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHOUT/Apache-AuthCookie-3.22.tar.gz ... OK
>
> Configuring Apache-AuthCookie-3.22 ... OK
>
> ==> Found dependencies: autobox
>
> --> Working on autobox
>
> Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CH/CHOCOLATE/autobox-2.82.tar.gz ... OK
>
> Configuring autobox-2.82 ... OK
>
> Building and testing autobox-2.82 ... FAIL
>
> ! Installing autobox failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1415007741.22940/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
>
> ! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'autobox' is not installed
>
> ! Bailing out the installation for Apache-AuthCookie-3.22.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

build.log file

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7014 on perl 5.010001 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
Work directory is /root/.cpanm/work/1415007741.22940
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/wget
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.23
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
Searching Apache2::AuthCookie on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Apache2::AuthCookie
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHOUT/Apache-AuthCookie-3.22.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Apache-AuthCookie-3.22.tar.gz
Entering Apache-AuthCookie-3.22
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Configuring Apache-AuthCookie-3.22
Running Makefile.PL
[   info] generating script t/TEST
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite autobox 1.1 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Apache::AuthCookie
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Test::More 0 ... Yes (1.001008)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.00)
Checking if you have Apache::Test 1.35 ... Yes (1.38)
Checking if you have Class::Load 0.03 ... Yes (0.22)
Checking if you have autobox 1.1 ... No
Checking if you have mod_perl2 1.999022 ... Yes (2.000004)
Checking if you have CGI 3.12 ... Yes (4.09)
==> Found dependencies: autobox
Searching autobox on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on autobox
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/C/CH/CHOCOLATE/autobox-2.82.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking autobox-2.82.tar.gz
Entering autobox-2.82
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.00)
Configuring autobox-2.82
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for autobox
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have Scope::Guard 0.20 ... Yes (0.20)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.00)
Building and testing autobox-2.82
cp lib/autobox.pod blib/lib/autobox.pod
cp lib/autobox/universal.pm blib/lib/autobox/universal.pm
cp lib/autobox.pm blib/lib/autobox.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for autobox ()
chmod 644 "autobox.bs"
"/usr/bin/perl" "/usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap "/usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/typemap"  autobox.xs > autobox.xsc && mv autobox.xsc autobox.c
gcc -c  -I. -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3 -Wall   -DVERSION=\"2.82\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.82\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE"   autobox.c
/bin/sh: gcc: command not found
make: *** [autobox.o] Error 127
-> FAIL Installing autobox failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1415007741.22940/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
-> FAIL Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'autobox' is not installed
-> FAIL Bailing out the installation for Apache-AuthCookie-3.22.
```

Comment: It would help if you could show us the content of /root/.cpanm/work/1415007741.22940/build.log

Comment: Did you tried to install autobox manually?

Comment: I have tried to do it through CPAN, but no success.

Comment: How could I install autobox manually?

Answer (score 1):

After looking inside the log files I found out that I a compiler was missing.

```
yum install gcc-c++
```